# Ways to take multiple variations of inputs to mean the same thing?

Tags: java, parsing, input, text, java.util.scanner

I have to make a text based game in Java for uni and I want to let users use multiple command variations and multiple names for items/NPCs. Whats the best way to do this?

For example, if i want people to go west i want people to be able to say
"Go west" or "Head West" or "Walk west", etc.

I understand I can do this with just many of these:

```
if (command.equals("head") || command.equals("walk") || command.equals("travel") || command.equals("go"))
```

but not only is this lengthy and ugly but with every single command, every single item and every single character it will become insanely long and inefficient. Is there any better way to do this that isn't insanely advanced? Thanks

Comment: You can just put the strings to an arraylist and iterate though to check the input.

Comment: Or you can just ignore what they type except for values like 'west', 'north', and 'south'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can ignore what user inputs except the real value you want, which I assume is the direction:

```
String lowerCaseCommand = command.toLowerCase()
if (lowerCaseCommand.contains("west") || lowerCaseCommand.contains("north") || so on...) {
   // do something.
}
```

Or you want something like this:

```
String[] array = {"head", "walk", "travel"}
for (String str : array) {
   if (command.equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
       // do something
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i guess this is a little nicer to look at. its just i wanted to avoid having so many of these. like id have to have one of these for each command, each item, each character, most of which only having one alternate variation. So even if i use this, ill just have hundreds of lines of if statements. maybe i could try put everything in a HashMap and have the variations as keys and the main command as the values to just replace it with.

Answer (score 1):

You could (if you wanted) use a **switch/case** block, for example:

```
switch (command.toLowerCase()) {
    case "head": case "walk": case "travel":
        callDoSomethingMethod();
        break;
    case "rest": case "sleep": case "passout":
        callAnotherDoSomethingMethod();
        break;
    default:
        System.err.println("Don't understand the command: '" + command + "!"
}
```